# Error between a differentiable function and tangent line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that the error between a differentiable function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and its tangent line $T(x)$ at $a$ satisfies $|f(x) - T(x)|\le C|x-a|$ where $C=\sup_{a\le y \le x}|f'(y) - f'(a)|$.

I'm honestly at a loss as to where to start. Any intuition would be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Two thing: Perhaps you might like to tell us what your have done, and do you mean $f'(x)$ instead of $f'(y)$?

Comment: according to the book its $f'(y)$, honestly, ive never seen anything in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(c)$$
for suitable $c$ between $a$ and $x$.    Rewrite this as
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(c)(x-a).$$

But the linear approximation $T(x)$ is given by $T(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$.

Put these two items of information together. We have $f(x)-T(x)=\dots$.